# How to share my app page in my facebook?

Tags: android

I can post my text to the facebook account through my app (facebook integration - using facebook sdk).

But I want to post/share my whole app page to my facebook account, that means, I have paint design in my app, so I want to share my designed image into facebook.

Here i paste the screenshots of my doubts, kindly check,[image]

but actual process which i have, when i click the facebook icon, the **Post to Wall** page is opened and I can type the text only liked in the second image,[image] after clicking the Share button in the above page, i get the output things in my facebook account as shown as,
[image]
but i want to share the whole page along with image to my facebook account, Now I hope you understand my question.give me the solution. Thanks

Comment: try to search before you ask here.. may have duplicates like below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095893/android-facebook-api-post-to-wall-with-image, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510071/facebook-api-android-wall-post-publish-with-image-attachment-not-working

Comment: ya I know that, unfortunately the stackoverflow closed my question which i before raised. thats why i ask the new one. Kindly provide the solutions, if you know. Thanks.

Comment: Check the sample code from here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk also refer previous commented message.

Comment: also refer here for more detail implementation at http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-facebook-sdk-to-post-status-from-android/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is also used to post only the text image only, Actually I want to share the image in the layout page. Please look this link, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluecode.photo.space.effects.fx&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5ibHVlY29kZS5waG90by5zcGFjZS5lZmZlY3RzLmZ4Il0.